# @media print doesn't override main style

Tags: css, printing, media-queries

In my page I have a left sidebar and a container, container has a margin-left because the sidebar is absolute positioned.

Now for printing I hide the sidebar and restore the margin-left of the container, but the margin is not restored.

These are the styles for my container and sidebar:

```
#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
#container {
    margin-left: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: margin-left .5s;
}

@media print {
    #sidebar { display: none;}
    #container {
        margin-left: 0px !important;
        padding: 0px !important;
    }
}
```

I'm using Chrome 40.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oddly enough, the issue can be resolved in Chrome by removing the transition within the `print` media query:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4s2xvdo1/)

```
@media print {
    #sidebar { display: none;}
    #container {
        margin-left: 0px !important;
        padding: 0px !important;
        transition: none;
    }
}
```

Without removing the transition, you can [reproduce the issue here](http://jsfiddle.net/wzet66wz/). Perhaps this is a rendering bug?

Answer (score 0):

Probably unrelated with this issue, but I had overriding problems because of this:

```
.sms-content {
    word-break: break-word;
    width: fit-content;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

@media print {
    pre.sms-content {
      line-height: 12px;
      font-size: 9.5px;
      padding: 7px;
    }
}
```

the definitions must be the very same, so I had to change it to:

```
@media print {
    .sms-content {
      line-height: 12px;
      font-size: 9.5px;
      padding: 7px;
    }
}
```